# Regular Expression, remove everything after last forward slash

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to use a regular expression within PowerShell to remove everything from the last slash in this string;

```
 NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName
 NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Dormant/DifferentArea/Surname, FirstName
```

I need to remove Surname, FirstName including the /. 
The string should look like this.

```
 NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT
```

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

I have tried this; `-replace '([/])$',''` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Replace `/[^/]*$` with an empty string

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. **-replace '/[^/]*$',''**

Comment: Can you explain that for me please?

Comment: It looks for a '/', followed by zero or more characters other than a '/', followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you. If I only want to keep the content after the last forward slash until '?' (question mark), then what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

check this regex http://regexr.com?2vhll
i can't test it on powershell but it work in the regex generator

```
/(?!.*/).*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require regular expressions:

```
PS> $cn = 'NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName' -split '/'
PS> $cn[0..($cn.count-2)] -join '/'
NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use regexes.
I believe this approach is probably easier to understand, after all regexes - in general - are hard to read:

`NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName` has a path-like structure (windows also supports the forward slash as a path separator), so we could use split-path to return the parent 'directory' path.

Because '\' is the default path separator, we need to replace the '\' with '/' after doing this:

```
(split-path NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName).replace('\','/')
# will return NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't require regular expressions:

Take a substring of your string starting at the beginning of the string and ending before the index of the last slash in your string:

```
PS> $indexoflastslash = ("NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName").lastindexof('/')
PS> "NorthWind.ac.uk/Users/Current/IT/Surname, FirstName".substring(0,$indexoflastslash)
```